# R : List as part of data frame

Tags: r

This is driving me nuts! I'm sure the answer is simple but I can't work it out!

I have long data with grouped variables. I have 'dcast' it into wide format, the idea being that I want to perform some calculations on groups and then melt again before plotting them.

I now have the wide dataframe which looks 99% correct. All of the results for 'StartTime' are stored as a list (a vector, I guess?) in a single cell of the dataframe.

To get here:

```
dw <- dcast(data,Volunteer~grpa, fun =list, value.var=StartTime)
```

[image: Example dtaframe]

I would have thought it should be a case of simply indexing the vector and calculating a mean of that. E.g. df$mean1 <- mean(df$group1) but this returns NA
Alternatively, if I do df$mean1 <- mean(unlist(df$group1)) I get the mean of the whole column of lists which is obviously not what I want.

In addition to the mean, I'd also like to calculate the SD of the data. When I work out the syntax this should be trivial. I'm sure there are several ways of doing this:

1. Work out what I'm doing wrong and just generate a mean from the list
2. Using a different function in the dcast command to generate a table with all the values, means & SD in separate columns
3. Converting the lists to columns (N.B the lists are all length 3, with one exception where there is missing data)
4. Perhaps there is a way of calculating the (groupwise) means from the long data

Any help will be gratefully received! Thanks.

EDIT: Here's the data via dput:

```
structure(list(Well = c("A02", "A03", "A05", "A06", "A07", "A09", 
"A10", "A11", "B01", "B02", "B03", "B05", "B06", "B07", "B09", 
"B10", "B11", "C01", "C02", "C03", "C05", "C06", "C07", "C09", 
"C10", "C11", "D01", "D02", "D03", "D05", "D06", "D07", "D09", 
"D10", "D11", "E01", "E02", "E03", "E05", "E06", "E07", "E09", 
"E10", "E11", "F01", "F02", "F03", "F05", "F06", "F07", "F09", 
"F10", "F11", "G01", "G02", "G05", "G06", "G07", "G09", "G10", 
"G11"), Volunteer = c(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 40, 40, 40, 40, 
40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 70, 70, 70, 70, 70, 70, 70, 70, 70, 72, 72, 
72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 
74, 74, 74, 74, 74, 74, 74, 74, 74, 999, 999, 999, 999, 999, 
999, 999, 999), group = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 
2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 
3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 1, 
1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3), StartTime = c(340, 330, 310, 315, 305, 
330, 335, 325, 440, 445, 450, 460, 465, 455, 405, 410, 415, 350, 
355, 360, 355, 360, 350, 375, 380, 385, 290, 295, 285, 280, 285, 
290, 315, 320, 310, 290, 295, 300, 385, 405, 380, 405, 395, 385, 
305, 295, 300, 295, 300, 290, 300, 320, 310, 395, 400, 385, 390, 
395, 375, 380, 370)), row.names = c(NA, -61L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: You would benefit from using a [tidy data format](https://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v059i10/v59i10.pdf). Personally, I have never needed a list column. They are not well supported in R.

Comment: @Roland I think I understand tidy data, and I have curated my outputs so they start in a tidy format. However, in this particular case, I want to calculate the % change relative to group 1 and then calculate means and SDs. I don't understand how one can calculate these things when the data is in long format. With wide format data it's child's play and I could do it in Excel very easily, although it's extremely time-consuming doing it multiple times over (for each variable).

Comment: @RonakShah - data added in original post.

Comment: Keep the data in long format. Don't you need `aggregate(StartTime~Volunteer + group, data, mean)` ?